# a simpler way to get variables from structs within structs

Tags: c, struct

It's been over a year since I last used C, so I'm pretty much back to basics.

I have this code as part of a larger file:

```
typedef struct 
{
    float ix;
    float iy;
    float iz;
} InitialPosition;

typedef struct
{
    InitialPosition init;
} Particle;

void particle()
{
    Particle p1 = 
    { 
        .init = { .ix = 10, .iy = 10, .iz = 10 },  
    };

    glPointSize(10);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(p1.init.ix,p1.init.iy,p1.init.iz);
        //glVertex3f( 0, 0, 0 );
    glEnd();
}
```

It works/appears correctly with my particle being plotted onto an axis, but it seems like there must be a quicker way to feed the variables from the struct into the `glVertex3f` method.
On the off-chance it makes any difference I'm using openGL & glut.

Should I also be using pointers? (If so an example of use would be great.) Like I said it has been a while so any help appreciated.

Comment: No part of this particular code example would be improved by using pointers.

Comment: @aschepler ok thanks :) I wasn't sure if it would be more efficient to have pointers to the structs, but if not then all the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions that take three separate parameters require that you break each value out.  If you're going to be using these calls a lot, you have two ways to make it more convenient.

1) make a helper function:

```
void myglVertexParticle(Particle * apoint) { glVertex3f(init->ix, init->iy, init->iz) ; }

myglVertexParticle( & (p1.init)) ;
```

2) use an expansion macro:

```
#define PARTICLE3f(uuu)  uuu.ix, uuu.iy, uuu.iz

glVertex3f( PARTICLE3f( p1.init)) ;
```

Most people are probably going to frown on the second choice from a style point of view, and a good optimizing compiler should make the first case run nearly as quickly as the second.

Comment: Interesting, would not have known how to do that. Thanks :)